# Convert object of any type to JObject with Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I often need to extend my Domain model with additional info before returning it to the client with WebAPI. To avoid creation of ViewModel I thought I could return JObject with additional properties. I could not however find direct way to convert object of any type to JObject with single call to Newtonsoft JSON library. I came up with something like this:

1. first SerializeObject
2. then Parse
3. and extend JObject

Eg.:

```
var cycles = cycleSource.AllCycles();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var vm = new JArray();

foreach (var cycle in cycles)
{
    var cycleJson = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cycle, settings));
    // extend cycleJson ......
    vm.Add(cycleJson);
}

return vm;
```

I this correct way ?

Comment: `JObject.FromObject(your_domain_object)` is what you are looking for.  See @L.B's answer.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

JObject implements IDictionary, so you can use it that way. For ex,

```
var cycleJson  = JObject.Parse(@"{""name"":""john""}");

//add surname
cycleJson["surname"] = "doe";

//add a complex object
cycleJson["complexObj"] = JObject.FromObject(new { id = 1, name = "test" });
```

So the final json will be

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "surname": "doe",
  "complexObj": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test"
  }
}
```

You can also use `dynamic` keyword

```
dynamic cycleJson  = JObject.Parse(@"{""name"":""john""}");
cycleJson.surname = "doe";
cycleJson.complexObj = JObject.FromObject(new { id = 1, name = "test" });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I am getting the below json while evaluating cycleJson, with additional braces. How can I remove that additional braces ???                                                                           
  {{
  "name": "john",
  "surname": "doe",
  "complexObj": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test"
  }
}}

Comment: @remyathekkuvettil it is not a valid json. You need some ad-hoc string manipulations.

Answer (score 40):

If you have an object and wish to become JObject you can use:

```
JObject o = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(miObjetoEspecial);
```

like this :

```
Pocion pocionDeVida = new Pocion{
tipo = "vida",
duracion = 32,
};

JObject o = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(pocionDeVida);
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
// {"tipo": "vida", "duracion": 32,}
```

Comment: Why not JObject.FromObject() instead of (JObject)JToken.FromObject() directly?

Comment: it gave me a `System.InvalidCastException`

Answer (score 3):

```
JObject.FromObject(obj);
```

Documentation [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
var cycles = cycleSource.AllCycles();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var vm = new JArray();

foreach (var cycle in cycles)
{
    var cycleJson = JObject.FromObject(cycle);
    // extend cycleJson ......
    vm.Add(cycleJson);
}

return vm;
```