# convert json objects from one format to another in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the lists of 5 product and price for 12 months in following format

```
 dynamic product = new JObject();
 product.ProductName = "Elbow Grease";
 product.Price = 4.90;
 product.year = 2016;
 product.month = 01;

 product.ProductName = "Jeans";
 product.Price = 4.10;
 product.year = 2016;
 product.month = 01;

 product.ProductName = "Jeans";
 product.Price = 2.90;
 product.year = 2016;
 product.month = 02;
```

and now i need to convert this json to another format as follows to send to my view

```
[
    {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 01,
        "Elbow Grease": 4.90,
        "Jeans": 4.10
    },
    {
        "year": "2016",
        "month":"02",
        "Elbow Grease": 0, //since not available
        "Jeans": 2.90
    }]
```

Comment: are you sure your json example is valid?

Answer (score 0):

**In case of MVC.**

Your Controller has method like:

```
public JsonResult Products()
{
   // ... your code
   return Json(new { products = product }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**In case of webservice, returned JSON value to AJAX call**

Return method is slightly modified.

```
 dynamic products = new DynamicJsonObject(new Dictionary<string, object>());
 // ... your code to fill up dictionary
 return Json.Encode(products);
```

p.s. Instead of JObject I would use ExpandoObject

p.p.s. But if you still want use JObject check this post [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21991318/4121714)

Comment: The problem is that the value of property 'ProductName' has been now the property and its value is the value of 'price' property.
Also, all the ProductName will be combined in same object with corr value for the same year/month.