# Parsing Array of objects JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

My JSON Input is below. Sry it is too long

```
{  
   "status":{  
      "success":[  
         {  
            "User":{  
               "id":"1377",
               "username":"Dr.Hema Sathish",
               "username_url":"dr-hema-sathish",
               "firstname":null,
               "lastname":null,
               "email":"madurai@sancheclinic.com",
               "password":"6c7ab07e828828206e3d7c56c3c35cfd383960cd",
               "user_level":"doctor"
            },
            "Speciality":{  
               "id":"2",
               "name":"Dermatology(Skin Specialist)",
               "slug":"dermatology-skin-specialist",
               "image":"1438693213.png",
               "status":"1",
               "created":"2015-07-08 03:35:57",
               "modified":"2016-09-13 13:58:36"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have downloaded JSON String from URL Successfully.

```
static void main
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        string json = webClient.DownloadString("http://myURL/");
        Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now I have to get User and Speciality objects. Its confusing to parse Array of Objects Json. How to parse it?

I have tried Deserialization. But it does not work.

How to parse it?

Comment: Did you check a search engine on `json c#`? You should use a library

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you have tried

Comment: I feel like today is going to be a JSON-converter day, every hour we get this kind of question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert object of any type to JObject with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991223/convert-object-of-any-type-to-jobject-with-json-net)

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json #jeroen van Langen

Comment: No it is valid. @Abhay

Comment: @arthy..this one is valid..the old one was invalid...:)

Comment: yes abhay, I accept this. But How to access User Object?

Comment: @arthy..check my original answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is invalid...here is correct json

```
   {
    "status": {
        "success": [{
                "User": {
                    "id": "1377",
                    "username": "Dr.Hema Sathish"
                },
                "Speciality": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Dermatology(Skin Specialist)"
                }
            },
            {
                "User": {
                    "id": "1390",
                    "username": "Dr.Nichita Balaji"
                },
                "Speciality": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Dermatology(Skin Specialist)"
                }

            }
        ]
    }
   }
```

You can create below classes to deserialize it using Newtonsoft

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class Speciality
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Success
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Speciality Speciality { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public List<Success> success { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to deserialize it

```
    string json =
        "   {\r\n   \t\"status\": {\r\n   \t\t\"success\": [{\r\n   \t\t\t\t\"User\": {\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"1377\",\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"username\": \"Dr.Hema Sathish\"\r\n   \t\t\t\t},\r\n   \t\t\t\t\"Speciality\": {\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"2\",\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"Dermatology(Skin Specialist)\"\r\n   \t\t\t\t}\r\n   \t\t\t},\r\n   \t\t\t{\r\n   \t\t\t\t\"User\": {\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"1390\",\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"username\": \"Dr.Nichita Balaji\"\r\n   \t\t\t\t},\r\n   \t\t\t\t\"Speciality\": {\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"id\": \"2\",\r\n   \t\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"Dermatology(Skin Specialist)\"\r\n   \t\t\t\t}\r\n\r\n   \t\t\t}\r\n   \t\t]\r\n   \t}\r\n   }";
    RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var successes = rootObject.status.success;
    var specialityObjects = successes.Select(success => success.Speciality).ToList();
    var users = successes.Select(success => success.User).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(users[0].id + " " + users[0].username);
    Console.WriteLine(users[1].id + " " + users[1].username);
    Console.WriteLine(specialityObjects[0].id + " " + specialityObjects[0].name);
    Console.WriteLine(specialityObjects[1].id + " " + specialityObjects[1].name);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

//OUTPUT

1377 Dr.Hema Sathish
1390 Dr.Nichita Balaji
2 Dermatology(Skin Specialist)
2 Dermatology(Skin Specialist)

Comment: How to display User and Speciality objects. Already I tried as you showed. but NullReferenceException is showing in this line. Console.Writeln(User.id);

Comment: if i try to access User details Using Console.WriteLine(tmp.status.success[0].User); It only shows filename.user in output.

Comment: @arthy...updated my answer...its LINQ to access objects ...dont forget to mark as answer if it is helping you

Comment: An object reference is required for non static fields,methods or property "RootObject.status" This error occurs. Help me pls

Comment: Thank you abhay. It Works..Thank u so much

Comment: @arthy...to appreciate my efforts..you can upvote my answer and mark it as accepted answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create classes according to JSON data set :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Speciality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you should be able to Deserialize using JSON .NET library

```
string json = webClient.DownloadString("http://myURL/");
User u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

There may be other library available, nonetheless [this one](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is working fine (and is available as NuGET package).

Please note this is only a sample, your code will miss several classes to properly parse your JSON (`Status` class, etc.).